# create nested lists from string with constant number of elements in each list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have found a very similar post where they did it with three items in each list, however I do not seem to understand how to toggle it to five.
Here is a string from a .csv file, split at new lines to create multiple strings:

```
['0,3,2,1,0', '0,1,2,3,0', '0,1,3,2,0', '1,0,2,3,0', '3,0,0,2,1', '1,0,2,3,0', '1,3,0,2,0', '0,0,1,0,0', '0,2,1,0,0', '3,1,0,2,0', '3,2,0,0,1', '2,0,0,3,1', '0,2,0,1,2', '2,0,3,0,1', '0,3,0,1,2', '2,3,1,0,0']
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
[['0,3,2,1,0'], ['0,1,2,3,0'], ['0,1,3,2,0'], ['1,0,2,3,0'], ['3,0,0,2,1'], ['1,0,2,3,0'], ['1,3,0,2,0'], ['0,0,1,0,0'], ['0,2,1,0,0'], ['3,1,0,2,0'], ['3,2,0,0,1'], ['2,0,0,3,1'], ['0,2,0,1,2'], ['2,0,3,0,1'], ['0,3,0,1,2'], ['2,3,1,0,0']]
```

This list of strings will have more items later on so I cannot manually set the boundaries where each list should start and end, this will take a lot of time.

The way they did it in the similar post was this:

```
i=0
new_list=[]
while i<len(data_list):
  new_list.append(data_list[i:i+3])
  i+=3
```

However, when I change my values to 5, it says list out of range. Could someone please explain how to increase the number of elements a list covers?

Comment: try this: `[[e] for e in l]`

Comment: I tried it but it just gives one number for each list

Comment: I commented this just at the same time as Ajax gave the answer below. How come this doesn't work? `l` is your long list.

Comment: Yes I understand that and I replaced L with my list name. it gives me this [['0'], [','], ['3'], [','], ['2'], (etc)

Comment: @kate then either your actual list is `['0', ',', '3', ',', '2', ...]`, or you're doing `[list(e) for e in l]`.

Comment: Strange, this is what I get for `l= ['0,3,2,1,0', '0,1,2,3,0', '0,1,3,2,0', '1,0,2,3,0', '3,0,0,2,1']`   ==> `[[e] for e in l]` ==> `[['0,3,2,1,0'], ['0,1,2,3,0'], ['0,1,3,2,0'], ['1,0,2,3,0'], ['3,0,0,2,1']]`

Comment: This is strange because I am definitely using square brackets. Also maybe it helps to point out that all the numbers are strings

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I'm sorry I didn't see the updates and was slow. I was about to delete my comment as it serves no purpose but the asker replied. Don't mind deleting it now.

Comment: I really don't know what the issue is. Maybe there is a way to modify that snippet of code in my post?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because the data structure is clearly not what is posted here.

Comment: I'm sorry to waste your time but the solution was that i had two variables data and data1 and I messed up where I used them because of their similar names but yes the solution works thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = ['0,3,2,1,0', '0,1,2,3,0', '0,1,3,2,0', '1,0,2,3,0', '3,0,0,2,1', '1,0,2,3,0', '1,3,0,2,0', '0,0,1,0,0', '0,2,1,0,0', '3,1,0,2,0', '3,2,0,0,1', '2,0,0,3,1', '0,2,0,1,2', '2,0,3,0,1', '0,3,0,1,2', '2,3,1,0,0']
final_s = [[i] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[['0,3,2,1,0'], ['0,1,2,3,0'], ['0,1,3,2,0'], ['1,0,2,3,0'], ['3,0,0,2,1'], ['1,0,2,3,0'], ['1,3,0,2,0'], ['0,0,1,0,0'], ['0,2,1,0,0'], ['3,1,0,2,0'], ['3,2,0,0,1'], ['2,0,0,3,1'], ['0,2,0,1,2'], ['2,0,3,0,1'], ['0,3,0,1,2'], ['2,3,1,0,0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution that is very Similar to your writed solution

```
  mylist=['0,3,2,1,0', '0,1,2,3,0', '0,1,3,2,0', '1,0,2,3,0', '3,0,0,2,1', '1,0,2,3,0', '1,3,0,2,0', '0,0,1,0,0', '0,2,1,0,0', '3,1,0,2,0', '3,2,0,0,1', '2,0,0,3,1', '0,2,0,1,2', '2,0,3,0,1', '0,3,0,1,2', '2,3,1,0,0']

i=0

newlist=[]

while (i< len(mylist)):
 newlist.append((mylist[i:i+1])) # just need add [ ]  

 i+=1

print newlist
```

output:

```
[['0,3,2,1,0'], ['0,1,2,3,0'], ['0,1,3,2,0'], ['1,0,2,3,0'], ['3,0,0,2,1'], ['1,0,2,3,0'], ['1,3,0,2,0'], ['0,0,1,0,0'], ['0,2,1,0,0'], ['3,1,0,2,0'], ['3,2,0,0,1'], ['2,0,0,3,1'], ['0,2,0,1,2'], ['2,0,3,0,1'], ['0,3,0,1,2'], ['2,3,1,0,0']]
```

> thanx @ Stefan Pochmann for its note